# SQL Migration Assistant for MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, azure

I want to convert my MySQL database to SQL Server, so that I can migrate my website into Azure.

I have two problems:

1. I downloaded **SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL**. I expect to see a "Connect to SQL Server" button, but there is only a "Connect to SQL Azure" button instead.
2. "OK" I said. "Why not convert it directly into Azure?" So I created an Azure account, and a SQL database in it. But when I tried to connect the MySQLToSQL to SQL Azure, it asks for user name, so I put my account email, "xyz@hotmail.com". It complained that "Cannot open server hotmail.com requested by the login". If I use "xyz", it complains "incorrect user name or password."

So what is my user name and password? I am totally new to Azure.

Comment: The Migration Assistant [does not force you to use Azure SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313095(v=sql.110).aspx). How did you try to connect? Did you check the `File` menu? Which version did you download? Where did you find it?

Comment: Yes I check the file menu, the only options is "Connect to SQL Azure". On the "About" menu, it displays "SQL Server 2016 Migration Assistent for MySQL v7.0.0".

Comment: Where did you find it? Migrating from MySQL isn't something people do every day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new project you specify the target database version in the `Migrate To` dropdown box. The default is `SQL Azure`. I suspect you didn't check the dropdown and created a project with the default value.

If you select another version, eg `SQL Server 2016` or `SQL Server 2014` you'll be able to use the `Connect to SQL Server` button.

[image: New Project dialog with on-premise selection]