# SSMA. Connect to Azure SQL Database Managed Instance to migrate from MySQL to Azure SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, sql-server-migration-assi

I just started using SSMA with the aim to migrate data from a MySQL server to my own Azure SQL database to work with the data in an Azure Logic app, which does not support MySQL very well. My idea is to run the an SSIS package to migrate data between the MySQL and SQL Azure Servers on a regular basis.

However I'm struggling connecting to the Azure SQL from SSMA. See below. I've given the user *db_owner*, *ddl_admin*, *db_datareader* and *db_datawriter* but still get this error. I can login with the user in SSMS without any issues to add tables, etc. What could be wrong? I am expecting to see a few test tables

```sql
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'mysq...'
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'mysq...'
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datawriter', N'mysq...'
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_ddladmin', N'mysq...'
GO
```

[image]

[image: SSMA]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got the connection bits working by changing project type in the new project dialogue. There are two different SQL Azure project types and I had selected the wrong one. See here [SQL Migration Assistant for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39726330/sql-migration-assistant-for-mysql?rq=1)